# wp-cli post create & media import issues

Tags: posts, customization, images, media, wp-cli

Been using wp-cli which I love.  But i'm trying to create new posts with a clickable image and the best wp-cli does with 1 command is a featured image which is not clickable (plus featured images are above my post's title & content).

This command is supposed to create a post with image, but instead it's an empty post (in the backend the image is "uploaded" to the post, **but the image is not displayed**):

```
wp media import ./FILENAME --post_id=$(wp post create --post_title='TITLE' --post_status=publish --porcelain)
```

**Is there a fix or a missing option?**  Again I don't want to use the featured image option since it puts the image above my title/content.

So now I've moved on to 2 commands:  Creating the post & then updating the posts' content field/value.

```
wp post update <ID> --post_content="<a href=""URL-TO-IMAGE""><img class=""size-full"" src=""URL-TO-IMAGE"" /></a>"
```

The problem with this is that I have to rearrange a bunch of values, so after I run this:

```
wp media import FILENAME
```

I'll need to do this:

```
echo `wp option get siteurl`/wp-content/uploads/`date +%Y`/`date +%m`/FILENAME
```

and so on

I'm running latest wp-cli & wordpress with the default plugins, so maybe I'm missing a plugin?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I just ended up doing a query on the database for the link of the image:

> wp db query "SELECT guid FROM wp_posts WHERE ID='ID_FROM_MEDIA_IMPORT'" --silent --skip-column-names

I wrote this bash script for the whole process:

post-create.sh PATH_TO_IMAGE.FILETYPE "TITLE"

```
imageID=$(wp media import $1 --porcelain)
imageLINK=$(wp db query "SELECT guid FROM wp_posts WHERE ID='$imageID'" --silent --skip-column-names)
wp post create --post_title="$2" --post_status=publish --post_content="<a href=""$imageLINK""><img class=""size-full"" src=""$imageLINK"" /></a>"
```